# Create test for a small method with final classes, void method and exception

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I am new with Test automation (`Mockito`, `JUnit`), and I do not get how I can test the following class. There are final classes, voids and Exception all together in the method and makes it pretty hard.

```
private final static String SERVER="http://testserver:9086";
private void checkServerr() throws myException {
    try {
        URL hp = new URL(SERVER);
        URLConnection hpCon = hp.openConnection();
        hpCon.connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new myException("Server " + SERVER + " not available");
    }
}
```

Comment: You test for all of the possible code paths in separate test cases (not to be confused with test classes). Using a tool like EclEmma will help you understand more about the concept of code coverage.

Comment: @MarkW +1, thanks for the tool! I installed it and used it. It seems the information it gives it is the same as the one that is included in RAD (it seems Eclipse does not have it). Richt click on Project --> Properties --> Code Coverage --> Enable code Coverage. And then run Tests to see how the impact is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading Janos' answer, I thought about the following.

Integrating the creation of the URLConnection in a Service class, `MyService.java`:

```
public class MyService {
    private static final String MYSERVER = "http://testserver:9086";

    public URLConnection createConnection(Properties properties) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        return new URL(MYSERVER).openConnection();
    }
}
```

And then myinitial class `myClass.java`:

```
public class myClass {
    private URLConnection serverConnection;
    private void checkServer() throws myException  {
        MyService service = new MyService();
        try {
            serverConnection = service.createConnection();
            serverConnection.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
             throw new myException("Server " + SERVER + " not available");
        }
    }
}
```

**Tests would be:**

```
@Mock
private URLConnection serverConnection;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testCheckInfrastructure() throws myException,
        IOException {
    Mockito.doNothing().when(serverConnection).connect();
    myClass.checkServer();
}

@Test(expected = myException.class)
public void testCheckServerException() throws myException, IOException {

    Mockito.doThrow(myException.class).when(serverConnection).connect();
    myClass.checkServer();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this testable, first you need to refractor it a little bit:

```
private void checkServerr() throws myException {
    return checkServer(SERVER);
}

protected void checkServer(String server) throws my exception {
    try {
        URL hp = new URL(server);
        URLConnection hpCon = hp.openConnection();
        hpCon.connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new myException("Server " + server + " not available");
    }
}
```

Now you can test the new protected method that takes the server address as a string.

I see only two things to test here:

- connection is successful. You will need a dummy server for that to make it possible
- connection failed, with expected exception myException

Comment: Personally, I would split the whole thing into more methods. The URL creation for example is something that stand on it's own - and can fail for every pre-defined constant value that might be in the code, so it would be good to be able to test that seperately, for example with a method `createUrl( String );` A unit test for that would ensure that every String url constant is actually a valid URL, thus preventing typos there.

Comment: voted up as gave me new ideas. I would agree as well with Florian. Will post my solution later